# How to get the detail of last call using callkit in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call, callkit

is it possible to access native call by using callkit.

I want the get name of last dialed/received number programmatically.

Comment: I think you can't because it's a privacy problem.

Comment: You can't. There is no access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a call using your own application with Call Kit integrated, you can store when the call ends locally. You can use that for the last call time.

You can use **CXCallObserverDelegate** delegate methods to see the change of observed behaviour of call like call ended.